# How to call set values into a <label> from database using php, ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have trouble getting my database values to a `<label>`.
I have a dropdown select option and I have wrote a `onchange()` function to it. When I select an option from dropdown, the php file should be run and execute and print the values/alert it...

Here's my `html`

```
<form method="POST">                                                                                             

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 field-label-responsive">
                                        <label for="name">Doctor ID</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">

                                                <select class="custom-select" id="selectDoctorID" name="selectDoctorID">
                                                    <option value="1">1</option>                                    
                                                    <option value="2">2</option>                    
                                                </select>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                        
                                </div>


                                <div class="row text-center">
                                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>



        </form>
```

Here's my `javascript/jquery`

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#selectDoctorID').on('change',function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "medical.php",
                        type:"post",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(result){
                            alert(result);
                        }
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>
```

Here's my `medical.php`

```
<?php
include './database_connect.php';
$id=$_POST['selectDoctorID'];
$query="SELECT * FROM doctor WHERE d_Id='$id'";

$result=  mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['d_fname'];
}
```

?>

Can anyone please help me??? I think I have done some mistakes in my `javascript` part, but I'm not sure.

Thank you!

Comment: You are not sending `selectDoctorID`, in the `$.ajax()` try with `$.ajax({
 url: "medical.php",
 type: "post",
 data: {"selectDoctorID ": $(this).val()},
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (result) {
  alert(result);
 }
});
`

Comment: Sir, the `result` inside the function(), can I have another name as my wish? what is `result` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your ID to your PHP and then replace your label text with your AJAX call answer :

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#selectDoctorID').on('change',function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "medical.php",
                    type:"post",
                    data:{selectDoctorID: $('#selectDoctorID').val()},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result){
                        $('label[for="name"]').text(result);
                    }
                });
            })
        });
```

Comment: Hello Sir, thank you, but what `dataType` I should give? `json` or `html` ?

Comment: Since you're asking for a contentType: 'json', I think you should return a JSON from your PHP using the json_encode() function instead of simply printing the values as text.

Comment: If you use the datatype `json`, don't forget to replace `echo $row['d_fname'];` by `echo json_encode($row['d_fname']);` in your PHP.

Comment: Hello Sir, How can I return a JSON from my PHP using the json_encode() function???

Comment: Thank you very much. but it is not wroking yet Sir... when I used `dateType : "html"` and echo it, it works without any error...

Comment: Then use `dataType:'text'` and don't encode your answer in JSON.